# MySQL - Figuring out what indexes to use, AND not working as expected

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have two problems here I'm trying to solve. First of all, the query, with values replaced with ? since I'm using a prepared statement:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  Messages t
    WHERE  perspective_user=?
      and  timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ?
      AND  timestamp_added = 
        ( SELECT  max(timestamp_added)
            from  Messages t2
            where  t2.author = t.author
              AND  t2.body = t.body
              AND  t2.timestamp = t.timestamp
              AND  t2.timestamp_added <= ?  )
      AND  convo_id IN (
        SELECT  convo_id
            FROM  Conversations
            WHERE  perspective_user=?
              AND  identity=?
              AND  timestamp_added=? );
```

The code is incredibly slow but works without the following line. With it included, it returns 0 results:

```
      AND  convo_id IN (
        SELECT  convo_id
            FROM  Conversations
            WHERE  perspective_user=?
              AND  identity=?
              AND  timestamp_added=? );
```

That line works fine on its own, and there are rows that satisfy the above requirements as well as that line. I'm wondering why it's behaving so odd.

The other thing I'm wondering about is what indexes to add. My first thought was three indexes: One on perspective_user, timestamp, timestamp_added, and convo_id, a second index on author, body, timestamp, and timestamp_added, and a final index on perspective_user, identity, and timestamp_added.

I don't really understand MySQL so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Do not ask multiple questions in a single post. Ask them separately.

Answer (score 0):

You only cross-reference convoid on the outer SELECT on t, but not the inner SELECT on t2.

Also, you can probably get away with just sorting on timestamp, descending, and then grabbing the first row - then you can do away with "t2" altogether.

Comment: The query will return thousands of rows, and I need them all.

Answer (score 0):

`IN ( SELECT ... )` is a very inefficient construct in MySQL.  Instead `JOIN Conversations ON convo_id = ... WHERE ...`.

The `added` game appears to be a "groupwise max".  See [*this*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/groupwise-max-in-mariadb/) for discussion of efficient ways to do that.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  If `body` is not `TEXT`, then you need `INDEX(author, body, timestamp, timestamp_added)`.  If that won't work, then we need to better understand the structure of `Messages`.