# MySQL - How do I know what indexes to use?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm trying to add indexes to the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM Messages t WHERE perspective_user=? and timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND 
timestamp_added = 
(select max(timestamp_added) from Messages t2 
where 
t2.author = t.author AND
t2.body = t.body AND
t2.timestamp = t.timestamp AND
t2.timestamp_added <= ?
) AND convo_id IN(SELECT convo_id FROM Conversations WHERE perspective_user=? AND identity=? AND timestamp_added=?);
```

My first thought was three indexes: One on perspective_user, timestamp, timestamp_added, and convo_id, a second index on author, body, timestamp, and timestamp_added, and a final index on perspective_user, identity, and timestamp_added. This doesn't work, however, and, as far as I can tell, takes the same amount of time to execute.

How do I add indexes to this query, and, more generally, how do I know how to add them properly in the future?

Comment: Execute the queries seperately with `explain select ...` to see how it performs

Comment: you add indices to the tables not the queries

Comment: Isn't this question a dup of part of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023274/mysql-figuring-out-what-indexes-to-use-and-not-working-as-expected ?  I have addressed the index questions there.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes to use?

> 1. Indexes depends on your needs query.
> 2. Mostly of indexes used is from on your where clause.
> 3. One best thing of indexes to use is your primary key.
> 4. Avoid creating to much indexes to your tables cause it could make your data become slower to your query.

See this [indexes tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm) for more details.